# Bootstrap Datepicker UI design issue

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using a bootstrap datepicker. Its working but look is not at all good.Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="row" align="center">
 <span>
   <b>Schedule:</b> <input class="datepicker" type="text"   
    id="attendancedate" name="attendancedate" value=@Model.AttendanceDate 
    onchange="return SubmitForm()">
 </span>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
 $(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#attendancedate").val('@Model.AttendanceDate');
        $("#attendancedate").datepicker('option', { dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' })

    })
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? 'Its working but look is not at all good', what is your question? what doesn't look 'good'?

Comment: Make sure you have included relevant .css - check F12 console for any errors? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">`

Comment: agree with @JamesP, this is mostly CSS so by targeting this file you can take control over its appearance. However, you might find it easier to edit the version that doesn't end in `..min.css`

Comment: @Alex you can see it looks big the previous and next months arrows not clearly visible. I want it to look more compact I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @JamesP I have the bootstrap-datetimepicker.css registered in bundles.config. 
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

Comment: And also
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/main.css",
                      "~/Content/accordion.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
                      "~/Content/tksaiptooltip.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery.timepicker.css"));

Comment: `bootstrap-datepicker.css` gives legacy support for twitter bootstrap v2, `bootstrap-datepicker3.css` is used for twitter bootstrap v3 support. Make sure you have correct css for your version of bootstrap.

Comment: Also `$("#attendancedate").datepicker('option', { dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' })` is not terminated with semi-colon - not sure if it will make a difference though.